# How to get server response code on D?

Tags: http, d

I need to check server response code in D. For example check if server return 404, 200 or some another code.

I looked at [std.net.curl](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_net_curl.html), but I do not understand how to use it.

I am not sure but possible I need to use option request
ex:

```
 import std.net.curl;
 import std.stdio;

void main()
{
    auto http = HTTP();
    options("dlang.org", null, http);
    writeln("Allow set to " ~ http.responseHeaders["Allow"]);
}
```

This codу do not work for me. I am getting next error:

```
F:\temp\1>app.exe
core.exception.RangeError@app.d(8): Range violation
----------------
0x0041DB08
0x00402092
0x00426D8E
0x00426D63
0x00426C79
0x0041D857
0x7636338A in BaseThreadInitThunk
0x77C79F72 in RtlInitializeExceptionChain
0x77C79F45 in RtlInitializeExceptionChain
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just attach a statusLine callback:

```
auto http = HTTP("dlang.org");
http.onReceiveStatusLine = (HTTP.StatusLine status){ responceCode = status.code; };
//attach onreceive callback as well
http.perform();
```

Comment: I am getting error "Error: undefined identifier StatusLine" what I should add to your example to get it's work, except main() function?

Comment: I can't understand why I am getting content of all page instead of server response code:

   `auto http = HTTP("dlang.org");
    http.onReceiveStatusLine = (HTTP.StatusLine status){ writeln(status.code); };
    http.perform();`

I had changed StatusLine to HTTP.StatusLine. Am I right understand that structures in D could be inner (one in another StatusLine in HTTP)?

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.net.curl;

void main()
{

auto http = HTTP("dlang.org");
http.onReceiveStatusLine = (HTTP.StatusLine status){ writeln(status.code); };
http.onReceive = (ubyte[] data) { /+ drop +/ return data.length; };
http.perform();

}
```

I would be very grateful, if somebody will explain me why I should to call onReceive and what data in onReceive braces means

Comment: you attach a callback to onReceive, the parameter passed in is the chunk of data that comes in from the server (usually what you are after when getting from a server)